# Convert File to Image

Tags: flutter, dart

I take a picture using ImagePicker that is saved like File. What I want is to convert it to png before upload it to FirebaseStorage. The problem is that when I try to convert it using this function:

File('test.png').writeAsBytesSync(encodePng(image));

it gave me error because the photo is saved like File not Image.
I've googled for some type of plugin or function to convert it from File to Image but have found nothing concrete.
Can anyone help me with this, please?

EDIT: Just to be sure I explained it clearly: I have photo 'photo 1.jpeg' that is stored like File, because this is what the ImagePicker does. Then I want to convert this File to Image and then convert it to .png

Comment: What is `encodePng`, and where does it come from?  If it wants byte data, you will need to use `File.readAsBytes()` first.

Comment: It comes from this package https://pub.dev/packages/image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to re-encode your image as a PNG, you will need to:

1. Read the bytes from the file via [`File.readAsBytes`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.1/dart-io/File/readAsBytes.html).  This will give you a `Uint8List` (which is compatible with `List<int>`).
2. You then will need to *decode* those bytes (e.g. with [`decodeJpg`](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/decodeJpg.html)) to transform them into `package:image`'s `Image` type.
3. Next you will need to use `encodePng` on the `Image`.  This will give you more bytes (as a `List<int>`).
4. Finally you will need to write those bytes to a file via [`File.writeAsBytes`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.1/dart-io/File/writeAsBytes.html).

All that said, it's rather pointless to decode a JPEG and to re-encode it as a PNG; you're just making the image take up more space than it needs to.

Answer (score 5):

Use this function:

```
Future<Image> convertFileToImage(File picture) async {
  List<int> imageBase64 = picture.readAsBytesSync();
  String imageAsString = base64Encode(imageBase64);
  Uint8List uint8list = base64.decode(imageAsString);
  Image image = Image.memory(uint8list);
  return image;
}
```

It takes picture in the **File** format and returns back the image in **Image** format.

> Don't forget to add **await** while calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would get the encoded path for the file.

```
File file = File('test.png);
String encodedImagePath = base64Encode(await file.readAsBytes());
```

Comment: can you be more specific about this? what I have to do with the encodedImagePath to convert it to Image?

Comment: Just to be sure I explained it clearly: I have photo 'photo 1.jpeg' that is stored like File, because this is what the ImagePicker does. Then I want to convert this File to Image and then convert it to .png