# Exporting Chat from whatsapp in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart

I am Exporting WhatsApp chat to my flutter app. It's showing all messages well but when I include media it doesn't show images in-app. It is giving a path like "IMG001010.jpg".
Can anyone tell me how to convert this into the image so it will be visible in my app?

Already tried solutions of this page:
[Convert File to Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58224596/convert-file-to-image)